# To access a USB device from a Perl module (Windows Platform)

Tags: perl, serial-port, usb, device

I am trying to access the usb device which is connected to my PC on windows platform. I used something like this:

```
use Device::USB;
   my $usb = Device::USB->new();
   my $dev = $usb->find_device($VENDOR, $PRODUCT);
```

What are the variables `$VENDOR, $PRODUCT` exactly to be sent as arguments?
How do i find them?

The driver for my device is already installed. Im using Windows 7 and Perl 5.18 version.

Please help in doing this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i find them?

You could use `$usb->list_busses()` to get an array of busses, and then check each device in `$bus->devices()` for its vendor and product id.

Comment: By `$bus` you mean, one of the busses returned by `$usb->list_busses()`?
What arguments should i pass to `$bus->devices()` function to get vendor and product id? Can you also point me to any material where i can refer to. Im also trying to send some messages to the connected USB device.

Comment: This was literally one mitute of googling `perl Device::USB`. Use the source, Luke!